# Why is this 2nd argument to SetFilePointerEx giving me an incompatible type error at compile time?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

```
LARGE_INTEGER li;
    li.QuadPart = 0;
    result = SetFilePointerEx(
            hFile,
            li.QuadPart,
            NULL,
            FILE_BEGIN
        );
```

I first tried to put a plain 0 in there, but later realized arg 2 is supposed to be a LARGE_INTEGER type, but this still is giving me a compile-time error which states:

> argtester.c:34:11: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of 'SetFilePointerEx'
>     result = SetFilePointerEx(

Comment: I have a question for you. What do you think that the error message means? When you read it (I hope you did read it, I know many novices ignore error messages) what did you think it meant?  I ask because if you understand the error message, then the problem and solution should be clear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the error message seemed incomplete to me. I'm not new to software, I just didn't understand this particular message ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

As in, Ok I get it's an incompatible type but I don't know what a compatible type would be in this case since I thought the QuadPart represented the structure. Given the fact that I've successfully reverse engineered drivers and kernels, and have written many other C programs successfully, I'm not too stressed about this little mishap.

Comment: A quick check of the documentation should set things straight. The function expects a `LARGE_INTEGER`, and that's what you need to supply.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I had checked the documentation before I posted this. A quick read of my original post would show that: " but later realized arg 2 is supposed to be a `LARGE_INTEGER` type." The problem was that I thought that the QuadPart represented the entire type. Kinda funny you asking me to check the documentation when you apparently didn't read my original post either. Kinda sounds like the same problem. Thanks for the lecture though... You're giving me useful, career-changing info here. Go ahead and downvote me some more. I really don't care.

Comment: I guess you can't learn anything from me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I learned plenty from zx485 because he didn't post condescending comments and have a rude tone with me. Perhaps you could learn something socially here. And I HAVE learned something from you. I learn every day, that's why I enjoy being a software researcher and why I stay up until 3 AM every night reading books.

Comment: What you could learn from me is to trust the compiler. You know what the compiler error means. You know what type the function expects. You think you are passing that, but the compiler disagrees, ergo what you are passing is not if the type you expect. From there the resolution is obvious. My point is mot about the specifics of this issue, but the process of solving it. I think a lot of people don't trust the compiler enough. That's what I see on this site.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Fair enough. Don't think I didn't learn from all this just because I got into a little back and forth with ya. I certainly did. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the whole `LARGE_INTEGER` instead of its `QuadPart` field as parameter:

```
LARGE_INTEGER li;
li.QuadPart = 0;
result = SetFilePointerEx(
        hFile,
        li,
        NULL,
        FILE_BEGIN
);
```

Then the TYPE_ERROR should vanish.